# Sinch on swift 2

Tags: swift, sinch

I am new in develop app for IOS and i am still learning but i can not handle a incoming call.

I do not know how to delegate and override the method. Can someone write a little example in swift 2.

Thats what i have until now, how can override the method didReceiveIncomingCall?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LoginView: UIViewController, SINCallClientDelegate, SINCallDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var labelUsuario: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameUsername: UILabel!
    @IBAction func buttonDesconectar() {
        //Add Disconnect code for VOIP

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.removeObjectForKey("usuario")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueLoginViewToInicio", sender: self)

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let vozIP = Sinch.clientWithApplicationKey(<APP_KEY>, applicationSecret: <APP_SECRET>, environmentHost: "sandbox.sinch.com", userId: "Roke" )

        vozIP.setSupportCalling(true)
        vozIP.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true)
        vozIP.start()
        vozIP.startListeningOnActiveConnection()   
    }
}
```

Comment: You should remove your application key and secret from the Internet!

Comment: Thank you, what a mistake :(

Comment: @Roke If not already done, go change your API keys *now*. StackOverflow is indexed by Google [almost instantly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281193/should-revisions-that-contain-credentials-be-deleted)...

Comment: Hello Eric, I send a email to Sinch Support. In my dashboard is not any button to delete or change it. They will delete this app shortly. Thank you for your advise.